# warning: passing argument 1 of 'cat' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c

I'm having trouble getting the parameters correct in my cat function. I would think since I'm changing temp that I would need to pass the address since I want to be able to see that in main. I think I'm getting screwed up by the decaying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
/* Swaps strings by swapping data*/
void swap2(char *str1, char *str2)
{
char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(str1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(temp, str1);
strcpy(str1, str2);
strcpy(str2, temp);
free(temp);
} 
void cat(char *temp, char *strings_line_tokens[])
{
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[1]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[2]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[3]);
}
int main()
{
    char str1[10] = "geeks";
    char str2[10] = "forgeeks";
    char temp[80] = {0};
    char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0};
    int lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter = 0;
    strings_line_tokens[0] = malloc(strlen("string")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[0], "string");
    strings_line_tokens[1] = malloc(strlen("string1")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[1], "string1");
    strcpy (temp,strings_line_tokens[0]);
    lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
    cat(&temp, strings_line_tokens)
    printf("temp is %s", temp);
    swap2(str1, str2);
    printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Swaps strings by swapping data*/
void swap2(char *str1, char *str2)
{
char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(str1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(temp, str1);
strcpy(str1, str2);
strcpy(str2, temp);
free(temp);
} 

void cat(char *temp, char *strings_line_tokens[])
{
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[1]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[2]);
}

int main()
{
    char str1[10] = "geeks";
    char str2[10] = "forgeeks";
    char temp[80] = {0};
    char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0};
    int lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter = 0;

    strings_line_tokens[0] = malloc(strlen("string")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[0], "string");

    strings_line_tokens[1] = malloc(strlen("string1")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[1], "string1");

    strings_line_tokens[2] = malloc(strlen("string2")+1);
    strcpy(strings_line_tokens[2], "string1");

    strcpy (temp,strings_line_tokens[0]);
    lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;

    cat(temp, strings_line_tokens);
    printf("temp is %s \n", temp);

    swap2(str1, str2);
    printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s\n", str1, str2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/rQM5qL

Comment: `strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[1]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[2]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[3]);` --> `strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[0]);
    strcat (temp,strings_line_tokens[1]);`

Comment: Thank you :). I added another variable so I didn't have to remove. Didn't catch that segmentation fault till you said that.

Comment: @M.M Sorry I fixed it.

Comment: An array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` has type `char[80]`, and `&temp` has type `char (*)[80]`, which is not compatible with `char *`, which `cat()` wants, as the message says.

The array `temp` will be automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array when it is used as function parameter (more generally, operands of operators other than `sizeof` and unary `&`), so you don't have to use `&` here.

In conclusion, try `cat(temp, strings_line_tokens);` (Don't forget the semicolon!)

Comment: Thank you :). I was trying to create a working example and missed it code.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php. An awesome professor taught me a long time ago warnings are just as important as errors so I started at the top with warnings

Comment: Is there a good rule of thumb when you need the `&`? I get confused by that quite often.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat(&temp, strings_line_tokens)
```

must be

```
cat(temp, strings_line_tokens);
                              ^ also don't forget the ;
```

`temp` after conversion has type `char *` but `&temp` has type pointer to `char [80]`.

Comment: Thank you :). I was trying to create a working example and missed it  http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php. An awesome professor taught me a long time ago warnings are just as important as errors so I started at the top with warnings.

Comment: Is there a good rule of thumb when you need the `&`? I get confused by that quite often.

Comment: @rockstar797 there is no rule of thumb, `&` is an operator and you use it when you need a pointer to an object.

Comment: I thought you needed `&` to get the address of variable so can change them in a function and see the result of whatever you did from wherever you called the function from. Won't the change be local to that function if you don't use `&`.